# what is the reason for error message ? I am using vs2015 express RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What is the reason for following message? This message appears when I select any menu in vs2015.

`The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.Parameter name: instantiation`

I am using vs2015 Express RC on Win8.1 Pro 64bit client OS.

Comment: Specifying the language would be helpful. So will a code snippet.

Comment: It is not language or code specific; Even if there is no solution (sln) loaded into vs2015, it does not alow launch a menu like file->open project etc

Comment: Sounds like a rogue extension. Uninstall them all and try again.

Answer (score 6):

*I was also facing the same issue. 
I removed below cache file and it worked for me.*

---

Execute this command in `powershell` :

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force ($env:APPDATA +  "\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache")
```

Comment: I was receiving this message when I tried to open any project or solution. Deleting the ComponentModelCache resolved the issue for me.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 just go looking for the 15.0 folder instead of the above 14.0 that has the 'ComponentModelCache" and delete it.  That fixed it for me.